# Convert STL map into a struct

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary, struct

I have a `std::map<string, double>` whose members look something like:

```
X = [{"N", 200}, {"sigma", 1.0}, {"T", .2}]
```

Now, given the struct `foo Y`:

```
struct foo {
    int N;
    double T;
};
```

Can I programmatically map the key/value pairs `X -> Y` *without writing a custom class for each `X -> Y` type mapping*? Note that:

1. `X["sigma"]` is not in `Y`, i.e. the mapping is not necessarily one-to-one
2. The type of `Y.N` is an int while `X["N"]` is a double.

I suspect the answer is no, unless some trickery is done at compile time.

**Edit:** It may not be clear what I'm looking for. A pseudo-code version for this example would look something like:

```
if("N" in X) -> Y.N = X["N"];
if("T" in X) -> Y.T = X["T"];
```

Or programmatically:

```
for key in Y:
    if (key in X) -> Y.key = X[key]
```

Comment: It's not clear from your question how you want to do the mapping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. C++ has no concept of reflection. At compile time, there's no `"foo::N"` string anymore. The compiler has converted all occurances of `foo::N` in the source code to a 0 byte offset within `Foo` objects. Also, you cannot enumerate class members at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

You want to set a *field* in an object of structure type based on the *value* of key in the map's elements (which is a *string*).  So, no it cannot be done at compile time.